# SQL Merge Duplicate Values in Table and Related Mapping Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge, duplicates

I have two tables.  One is the parent data table, the other is a mapping table for fulfilling a many-to-many relationship between this parent data table and the main table.  My problem is that the parent and mapping tables have duplicate values that need to be merged.  I can seemingly remove the duplicates from the parent table, but the mapping table needs to have the duplicate data merged in the same fashion.  There is a FK and related cascading delete/update on the Mapping Table. How do I ensure the merges from the following statement also get reflected in the Mapping Table?

*Before*

**Parent Table_A**:

```
| ID   | ProductName | MFG_ID  |
|------+-------------+------------+
|  1   |  ACME_123   |    123     |
|  2   |  ACME_123   |    456     |
```

**Mapping Table**

```
| ID   | MainRecordID | ParentTable.MFG_ID|
|------+--------------+-----------------------+
|  1   |      1       |          123          |
|  2   |      2       |          456          |
```

*Desired After*

**Parent Table_A**:

```
| ID   | ProductName | MFG_ID|
|------+-------------+------------+
|  1   |  ACME_123   |    123     |
```

**Mapping Table**

```
| ID   | MainRecordID | ParentTable.MFG_ID|
|------+--------------+-----------------------+
|  1   |      1       |          123          |
|  2   |      2       |          123          |
```

**Proposed Code to Merge Table_A Duplicates**

```
MERGE Table_A
USING
(
SELECT 
MIN(ID) ID,
ProductName,
MIN(MFG_ID) MFG_ID,
FROM Table_A
GROUP BY ProductName
) NewData ON Table_A.ID = NewData.ID
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET
Table_A.ProductName = NewData.ProductName
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN DELETE;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split it into two separate statements wrapped in an explicit transaction instead of a merge. Something like this:

```
declare @src table
(
    Id int,
    ProductName varchar(128),
    MFG_ID int
)
set xact_abort on

insert into @src
select
    Id = min(ID),
    ProductName = ProductName,
    MFG_ID = MIN(MFG_ID) ,
from Table_A
group by ProductName

begin tran

    delete o
    from Table_A o
    where not exists
    (
        select 1
        from @src i
        where o.id = i.id
    )

    update t
    set ProductName = s.ProductName
    from Table_A t
    inner join @Src s
        on t.Id = s.Id

commit tran
```